# SQL table design with common and distinct data

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm new to SQL and was wondering how to design tables when some data is common and some data is distinct. This is not a real example, but it illustrates the point. I want to store data about various items. All items have some common data - `ID, Name, Description, CountryOfOrigin, UseByDate`, etc. However, depending on the type of item, there are specific attributes that need to be stored, which are distinct for this type. It's a bit like object inheritance, there is a common root type, and various specialisations of the root type.

I could create different tables, one for each item type, but then each table will have its own `Name, Description, CountryOfOrigin, UseByDate`, etc. So if I wanted to list items by `UseByDate`, I would have to search multiple tables. This doesn't sound like a good approach.

So then I'm thinking, maybe I could have a single table called Items with common data and this somehow would reference other tables which store item type with its specific data. See the examples below:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ItemID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Name text, -- Brand specific name or similar
    Description text,
    CountryOfOrigin text,
    UseByDate date
);

CREATE TABLE MilkVariety
(
    Type milk_type, -- FullFat, Skimmed, etc
    VolumeLitres integer,
    FatContent integer,
    PricePerLitre money
);

CREATE TABLE BreadVariety
(
    Type bread_type, -- White, WholeGrain, Baguette, etc
    WeightKilos integer,
    SugarContent integer,
    PricePerKilo money
);
```

But I'm not sure how `Items` table could reference `MilkVariety` or `BreadVariety`. I could introduce foreign keys, but then it looks like I'd have to have multiple such keys for each item type. And this doesn't sound right, as a single item cannot be both milk and bread type.

Any suggestions on how these things should be handled? Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell from your example.  Are varieties always going to have type, weight / volume, sugar / fat / carb content, and price per measure attributes?

Comment: Yes, plus various other attributes only specific to that type/variety. For example MilkVariety could  be (FullFat, 1.0, 30, 0.5) and table Items could have two items of the same milk variety but from different suppliers, so brand name, country of origin and use by date could be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, based on your comment, that a variety of food will have consistent attributes.

Your Item table looks fine.  I've added a couple of columns at the bottom.

```
Item
----
Item ID
Name
Description
Origin Country
Use By Date
Item Variety
Variety ID
```

The Item Variety is a Varchar that describes the variety, as in "bread", "milk".  The Variety ID is a foreign key to the Variety table.

```
 Variety
 -------
 Variety ID
 Type
 Measure Type
 Measure Amount
 Content Type
 Content Amount
 Price per measure
```

Since all the varieties are in one table, you can join the Item and Variety tables easily.  However, you'll need to interpret what you've read from the database, probably in some programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you've aggregated all variety types into a single table called Variety. This works OK with such a simple example, but imagine the variety type could contain very different lists of attributes. For one type of variety a table could have 5 columns, for another type it could have 25 columns, which contain completely different data. Putting them all into a single variety table would be quite messy. This doesn't scale well with many different variety types. I kinda wanted to figure out how to link Items table to multiple Variety tables, or is this not practical/possible?

Comment: @SadClouds: You said in your comment that all varieties have the same attributes.  If they don't, then you're going to have to use some form of  entity attribute value model.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, in your example the *whole heading* of `xVariety` tables is *unique and irreducible* (`KEY`). Let us accept that, and also agree that we are happy tables are in `1NF` and leave it at that.
Let us also agree that number of `xVariety` tables is manageable, say less than 30 -- *not recommended* for more.

#### Option 1

This is the preferred option.

Starting with new `Variety`, supertype of all other `xVariety` tables.
`VAR_ID` may be an (auto-increment) integer generated in (for) this table; `VAR_TYP` is discriminator.
Create a new `{VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}` in this table before inserting a new row in any of `xVariety` tables,

```
-- Variety VAR_ID of type VAR_TYP exists.
--
Variety {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}
     PK {VAR_ID}
     SK {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}

CHECK (VAR_TYP IN ('Bread', 'Milk'))
```

`xVariety` subtypes are exclusive, so `VAR_TYP` is added to each subtype for better control, note `FK {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}`.

```
MilkVariety {
        VAR_ID
      , VAR_TYP   DEFAULT 'Milk'

      , MilkType    -- FullFat, Skimmed, etc
      , VolumeLitres
      , FatContent
      , ...  -- Other columns specific to this variety
      }
   PK {VAR_ID}
   AK {MilkType, VolumeLitres, FatContent, ...}

           FK {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP} REFERENCES
      Variety {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}

      CHECK (VAR_TYP = 'Milk')


BreadVariety {
        VAR_ID
      , VAR_TYP   DEFAULT 'Bread'

      , BreadType   -- White, WholeGrain, etc
      , WeightKilos
      , SugarContent
      , ...  -- Other columns specific to this variety
      }
   PK {VAR_ID}
   AK {BreadType, WeightKilos, SugarContent, ...}

           FK {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP} REFERENCES
      Variety {VAR_ID, VAR_TYP}

    CHECK (VAR_TYP = 'Bread')
```

`Items` can now reference `Variety`.

```
Items { ItemID
      , Name_
      , Description
      , CountryOfOrigin
      , UseByDate

      , VAR_ID
      }
   PK {ItemID}

   FK {VAR_ID} REFERENCES Variety {VAR_ID}
```

#### Option 2

This option provides less control, but may be easier to manage.

Each table has its own independent (auto-increment) `ID`; again adding `VAR_TYP` for better control.

```
MilkVariety {
         MILK_ID
       , VAR_TYP    DEFAULT 'Milk'

         MilkType      -- FullFat, Skimmed, etc
       , VolumeLitres
       , FatContent
       , ...  -- Other columns specific to this variety
       }
    PK {MILK_ID}
    AK {MilkType, VolumeLitres, FatContent, ...}

    CHECK (VAR_TYP = 'Milk')


BreadVariety {
         BREAD_ID
       , VAR_TYP    DEFAULT 'Bread'

         BreadType     -- White, WholeGrain, etc
       , WeightKilos
       , SugarContent
       , ...  -- Other columns specific to this variety
       }
    PK {BREAD_ID}
    AK {BreadType, WeightKilos, SugarContent, ...}

    CHECK (VAR_TYP = 'Bread')
```

Now a *view* `{VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}`.

```
-- view (logically)
--
Variety {VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}
     PK {VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}
```

An example :

```sql
CREATE VIEW Variety AS
SELECT VAR_TYP
     , MILK_ID AS VAR_TYP_ID
FROM MilkVariety
UNION
SELECT VAR_TYP
     , BREAD_ID AS VAR_TYP_ID
FROM BreadVariety ;
```

Note that the view must `UNION` all `xVariety` tables. It would be good if we could (somehow) materialize this view, then it could be possible `FK` to it. But, leaving this discussion for some other time.

Adding  `{VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}` to `Items`

```
Items { ItemID
      , Name_
      , Description
      , CountryOfOrigin
      , UseByDate

      , VAR_TYP
      , VAR_TYP_ID
      }
   PK {ItemID}

     -- how to implement this?
     FK {VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID} REFERENCES
Variety {VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}
```

The `FK` must be implemented *somehow*. If the view is materialized, depending on a RDBMS, it may be possible to specify the constraint in SQL; otherwise, the application *must* take care of it.

If it is the case that `xVariety` tables rarely change, say once per week, then view `Variety {VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}` may actually become a table. The same process that loads `xVariety` tables may then populate the table using the query. In that case it would be possible to have `FK` to it from `Items`.

Use `{VAR_TYP, VAR_TYP_ID}` when joining, to make sure not to join to a wrong table.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Items        AS a
JOIN BreadVariety AS b ON  b.VAR_TYP_ID = a.VAR_TYP_ID
                       AND b.VAR_TYP    = a.VAR_TYP
WHERE a.CountryOfOrigin = 'US';
```

#### Notes

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```